# Fibers/node-gyp hanging on Yarn install on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-gyp, webdriver-io, yarnpkg

Looks like `wdio` has `fibers` as a dependency, which uses `node-gyp`, which apparently won't run on Windows without Python 2.7.

Now that I have that installed, I don't get the `"missing PYTHON"` error, but it hangs forever on whatever that command is doing - fibers.

[image: Hangs forever on fibers]

Comment: Do you have other versions of python installed?

Answer (score -1):

The question itself is not related to WebdriverIO, please see node-gyp doc https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows